# Modifying req.url doesn't update the url parameters (req.query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Since Google Sitemap doesn't allow **`&`** in its **XML**. I've escaped the url (like '`/path?a=123&b=hello`') which contains two parameters now becomes `/path?a=123%26b=hello` and I thought browser will automatically unescape the url back. But it's not. And Google bot is giving errors.

So I add a middleware function on top of the stack before calling the mentioned route.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        debug(req.url);
        req.url = unescape(req.url);
        debug(req.url);
        // This works as expected
        next();
});
```

But I when i perform `req.query.a` and `req.query.b` (Google bot is visiting using the escaped URL i.e `/path?a=123%26b=hello`), It's giving the original value i.e `req.query.a gives 123%26b=hello` and `req.query.b gives undefined` and when I check `req.url` it is giving the unescaped url which is correct.

What do you suggest?

**UPDATE:**

One quick solution I could think of is (I haven't tried this but I think it will work)

```
// After unescaping req.url
// test.com/path?a=123&b=hello
var query = req.url.split('?')[1].split('&');
var a = query[0].split('=')[1];
var b = query[1].split('=')[1];

// It looks very dirty
```

Comment: Have you tried `/path?a=123&amp;b=hello` in XML?

Comment: @user3173842 Thanks. It's the exact clean solution I needed. Please write as an answer so that I could accept it and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML you should escape `&` as `&amp;`:

```
/path?a=123&amp;b=hello
```

`%26` is used for the `&` sign within a value as you already found out.

Comment: Thank You. You stopped me from writing a lot of dirty hacks. :D

Comment: If it looks bad there is probably a better way ;) np

Answer (score 0):

**Try `HTML5 History API` it will work :**

[History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: I would like to know first if there's any way to do this from server side. After that I'll try your solution.

Comment: You can chane the url parameters using server side also but for that you have to redirect the page that will reduce the user experience..cuz browser always work on client side..so, please try `History.pushStste()` API.